# Change color of CoppeliaSim shapes with Python

Tags: python, colors, simulator, robotics

I am using the CoppeliaSim Regular API with Python.

To set a color to my primitive shapes I am using the method setShapeColor().
To set a shape green I have the following code.

## code to set a shape green

sim.setShapeColor(capsuleHandle, None, sim.colorcomponent_emission, [0, 255, 0])

However I am not convinced with the result. Although it is green, it looks quite pale and very shiny/reflective.

But from the setShapeColor() there are 2 parameters that I do not understand well.
https://www.coppeliarobotics.com/helpFiles/
What should the string colorName contain? Are there already predefined color names? Or it is that a tag just for me? Or what is the use of that string?

Also I do not understand the color components.
https://www.coppeliarobotics.com/helpFiles/en/apiConstants.htm#colorComponents
The documentation only gives the names but they do not explain what is the purpose of each component or when to use each.

So can someone please:

1. Explain me how to use the colorName string and the color components
2. How can I not only change the color of the shape, but also control the intensity of the color and if it shiny or dull.
3. I also need to control the transparency of the shape. How to do that?

Thank you :)

- Read the Regular API documentation
- Trying all the color components but the result was always the same
- For the transparency I tried: Using the transparency component, in the RGB instead of sending a list send a single value for the transparency, send a list with just 1 value, send a list with 4 values (RGB + transparency).

Comment: It is a proprietary software. Why not ask the vendor? See [the official forum](https://forum.coppeliarobotics.com/).